# Catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block) in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to stack multiple exception conditionals into a single line. How can I do this in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the type of the error in the catch block, usually using an if-else tree.  Anything else will naturally follow from the if-else syntax.

Here's what I would consider the "canonical" way of doing it:

```
try 
    # throw some error here
catch e 
    if e isa ErrorException
        # do something
    elseif e isa ArgumentError
        print("So much for multiple dispatch")
    else
        rethrow(e)
    end
end
```

You could shrink this into one line using the ternary operator, but it's probably not worth it.